# Pad a file using awk

Tags: awk

So I have this working on a server with awk 3.1.7 and when I try using on a server with awk 4.0.2 it does not seem to work. I am just trying to add a filename 14 digits, is the goal. I don't have the perl version on rename just in case it is brought up.

Anyhow this is my code

```
ls 800001.1.pull | awk -F'.pull' '{ printf "%s %014s.pull%s\n", $0, $1, $2; }' | xargs -n 2 mv
```

I get this error mv: ‘800001.1.pull’ and ‘800001.1.pull’ are the same file

```
ls 800001.1.pull | awk -F'.pull' '{ printf "%s %014s.pull%s\n", $0, $1, $2; }' | xargs -n 2 mv
mv: ‘800001.1.pull’ and ‘800001.1.pull’ are the same file
```

This same things that has been running on the other server for a few years and I don't get an error, I get a file named:

```
ls 800001.1.pull | awk -F'.pull' '{ printf "%s %014s.pull%s\n", $0, $1, $2; }' | xargs -n 2 mv
000000800001.1.pull
```

and this is why I said this:

I will take it that the newer awk handles delimiters different?

The expected output is 000000800001.1.pull

The original file needs to be 0 padded to 14.

Thanks!

Comment: No, the newer awk does not handle delimiters differently. Whatever the problem is, it's not that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ echo 800001.1.pull | awk -F'.pull' '{ new=sprintf("%14s%s",$1,FS); gsub(/ /,0,new); print $0, new }'
800001.1.pull 000000800001.1.pull

$ echo 800001.12.345.pull | awk -F'.pull' '{ new=sprintf("%14s%s",$1,FS); gsub(/ /,0,new); print $0, new }'
800001.12.345.pull 0800001.12.345.pull
```

Comment: Added the expected output. Thanks!

Comment: No, because just replacing the s with a d does not give the correct file name. I need the resulting file to be named 000000800001.1.pull. It cuts out the .1 when doing that.

Comment: OK - what are you trying to do exactly? You have a file that ends in `.pull` which you're splitting into 2 fields at `.pull` so the 2nd field is always null but then you're using `$2` in your printf... What part is supposed to be 14 chars long? Is the `.1` that's now missing part of that 14 chars? Is it always a single digit? Is there sometimes text after the `.pull`?

Comment: There is never text after the .pull. It needs padded 14 800001.1, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Also the .1.pull could be .2 or some other number.
So it could be 800001.2.pull or  800001.3.pull or  800001.14.pull and so on and so on.

Comment: We have seen 800001.1.1.pull also. I guess it needs to be padded 14 for anything that is before the .pull

Comment: That seemed to work great. I will accept this as the answer. I do wonder why what is running on one server does not work on this one. I think the OS is newer Redhat. Ed, I do appreciate your time!!

Comment: Maybe there is simply a bug in the older awk version? You're welcome.